# VueJS reference a local JSON file outside of build

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, webpack

I have some JSON data that I'm working with in a Vue project. In development I'm referencing and using the JSON data as shown below

```
<script>
import Versions from './../JSONVersionData/versions.json'

export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            Versions
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

My webpack configuration compiles all my Javascript to an app.js file in dist. This means that the JSON files are compiles  into this app.js file.

My aim is to allow the `versions.json` file to manually edited in the dist file so it can be maintained without needing the end user to recompile the JS assets.

Is this possible? Can I make my Javascript look for a local copy of the JSON data file rather than a bundled version of the file?

Comment: You can put the JSON file inside the `/project/public` folder - then it will be copied intact to the `/project/dist` folder. You will then have to fetch the file with AJAX from your main code.